# Exclude values from ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting

I would like to generate `ArrayPlot` from data below

```
values = {1534, 1404, 1484, 1564, 1414, 1464, 1534, 1454, 1414, 1444, 
1584, 1534, 1604, 1474, 1554, 1484, 1414, 1484, 1604, 1474, 1484, 
1826, 1856, 1806, 1916, 1826, 1786, 1906, 1846, 584, 724, 544, 644,
1409, 1309, 1659, 1389, 1359, 1389, 2400, 1389, 2400, 2650, 3550, 
3550, 3500, 1409, 1289, 1559, 1409, 1609, 1409, 1339, 1409, 1609, 
2874, 1609, 4000, 4450, 4000, 3770, 4000, 2500, 2650};
mat = Partition[values, 8, 8];
```

However, only values running from `1000-5000` should be plotted.

```
colours = Reverse[{Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue, Magenta}];
z1bound = 1000;
z2bound = 5000;
colourfunc = 
Function[Blend[Reverse[{Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue, Magenta}], 
Rescale[#, {z1bound, z2bound}]]];
```

Values outside this interval, such as `584,724,544,644` should be excluded from an `ArrayPlot`(e.g. plotted in a **white colour**). I have rescaled my `colourfunc` in this way but the above-mentioned values are plotted in the `ArrayPlot`anyway (in a Magenta colour).

```
arrayplot = 
ArrayPlot[mat, ColorFunction -> colourfunc, 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colourfunc, {z1bound, z2bound}}], 
Epilog -> {Black, 
MapIndexed[Text[#1, Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, Reverse[mat], {2}]}]
```

[image: ArrayPlot]

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Maybe use `Clip[mat, {1000, 5000}, {White, White}]`

Comment: "The barlegend should run from 1000 corresponding to Magenta" and "the lowest value 1289 does not correspond to "lowest" colour in the colourfunction (pink colour)" contradict each other. Which is correct?

Comment: @Coolwater, Yes you are right, it contradicts each other. The bar legend should run from `1000`(`Magenta`) to `5000` (`Red`). I made a mistake in that previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

```
colourfunc2 = Function[Blend[Reverse[{Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue, Magenta}], #]]; 
ArrayPlot[mat /. x_ /; (x < 1000 || x > 5000) :> None, 
 ColorFunction -> colourfunc2 , 
 Epilog -> {Black, MapIndexed[Text[#1, Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, Reverse[mat], {2}]},
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{If[# < 1/6 || # > 5/6 , White, 
      colourfunc2[Rescale[#, {1/6, 5/6} , {0, 1}  ]] ] &, {0, 6000}}]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ArrayPlot[mat /. x_ /; (x < 1000 || x > 5000) :> White, 
 ColorFunction -> colourfunc, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ArrayPlot[mat ,
 ColorFunction ->(If[# < 1000||# > 5000, White, colourfunc @ #]&), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

> same picture

```
ArrayPlot[mat , ColorRules -> {_?(# < 1000 || # > 5000 &) :> White},
  ColorFunction -> colourfunc, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

> same picture

Note: You can also use `None` instead of `White` to color the selected cells in background color.

Comment: @Moonwalk, does `colourfunc2= 
  Function[Blend[Reverse[{Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue, Magenta}],#]];
ArrayPlot[mat /. x_ /; (x < 1000 || x > 5000) :>None, 
 ColorFunction -> colourfunc2]` give the desired result?

Comment: Thank you @kglr. It is almost perfect. Could you also adjust barlegend in the same way?

Comment: @Moonwalk, please see the update.

Comment: ,it's almost flawless :). The barlegend should run from `1000` corresponding to **Magenta** colour to `5000` corresponding to **Red** colour. I tried to adjust the barlegend in this way: `BarLegend[{If[# < 1/5, White, colourfunc2[Rescale[#, {1/5, 1}, {0, 1}]]] &, {0, 5000}}, Ticks -> Table[i, {i, 1000, 5000, 500}]]]`. However, the colours and corresponding values on barlegend are not in correspondence to `ArrayPlot`. Notice e.g. value `4450` which in the `ArrayPlot` is plotted in **Red**, but in the `BarLegend` its value corresponds to **Yellow/Orange**.